# Toggle class on click add class and remove

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

if i click item i need to add class name and if click same item need to remove the class for ngFor loop

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of statementresponse;let i=index" class="cust_delay delay" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == x}" (click)="listClick($event, x)" >
</ion-item>

selectedItem:any;
listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = !newValue;.
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of the ways you can do this is having your items have an **"active"** property, something like this:

```
items = [
  {name:'one', active:false},
  {name:'two', active:false},
  {name:'three', active:false},
];
```

And inside the template represent them like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" 
    (click)="toggleClass(item)" 
    [ngClass]="{'active': item.active}">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

And finally the **toggleClass()** method just toggles the active state of the clicked item:

```
toggleClass(item){
  item.active = !item.active;
}
```

---

### [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdmfuk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

**HTML**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of statementresponse;let i=index" 
     class="cust_delay delay"[class.active]="selectedItem == i" 
     (click)="selectedItem=i" >
      {{x}}
</ion-item>
```

**Typescript:**

```
selectItem=-1
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-u93mhd?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can store a boolean for that value somewhere. like in the object itself and then use

`<ion-item [class.myClass]="item.myClass"></ion-item>`
`item.myClass` being the boolean

and on click flip that value

`item["myClass"] = !item["myClass"]`

Comment: how can add css class based on condition in Ngfor item?
this added class for all items